# How to Authorization parameters from Schoology

Tags: schoology

How do I get the authorization parameters (key and secret info) from Schoology? Is it something that Schoology provides based on the school system that is their customer? Or is it something that must be obtained directly from the school system?

It is also not clear whether Schoology requires the customer (the school system) to keep an intermediate server or access data directly on the Schoology servers.

I applied to Schoology, as a developer but was rejected without an explanation. I figure it might be because I'm a parent not an organization. So any help with that would be helpful. I didn't get any details on requirements to be a developer.

I'm trying to build something for my son to reformat his course assignments.

Thank you for any help.
Mariam

Answer (score 0):

Just use [districtname].schoology.com/api